# QT - How set filename encoding to cyrillic

Tags: c++, qt, file, encoding

when creating a file named "абцде"
the filename is written with hieroglyphics

```
const QByteArray data = "someData"; // some Data
QString fileName = "абцде.txt"; // fileName
QFile localFile(fileName.toUtf8());
localFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
localFile.write(data);
localFile.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with the filename? Raw string literals with non-ASCII characters are prone to getting malformed -- which is why Qt provides the [QStringLiteral](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral) macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sources are UTF8 encoded, then you should use this ([Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8-1))

```
QString fileName = QString::fromUtf8( "абцде.txt" ); // fileName
```

If your sources has other encoding then you can select other functions like `QString::fromLocal8Bit`.

Comment: That was true for Qt 4. In Qt 5, you should use `QStringLiteral`!

Comment: @Kuba Ober At the question there is nothing about Qt version. I give answer that will work everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

These lines of code form qt man on i[nternationalization](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html)
can help. ( QString use Unicode originally ).

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName( "Windows-1251" );
QByteArray encodedString = codec->fromUnicode( "абцде.txt" );
```

You might need to play around with encodings ( "Windows-1251" ), kind of brute force method.